# Why does adding a bounty to your own question prevent it from being voted closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounty

I find it a little annoying that users can "protect" bad questions with bounties but the ability to do this to your own question seems like a particularly blatant loophole. ELU does not close questions very quickly and I've now hit this problem twice in the past few weeks.

Why does adding a bounty on your own question prevent it from being voted closed?

Comment: Ahh, MrHen... Canst thou, O partial sleep, give thy repose
To the wet sea-boy in an hour so rude,
And in the calmest and most stillest night,
With all appliances and means to boot,
Deny it to a king? Then happy low, lie down!
Uneasy lies the head that would wear a crown.

Comment: I was about to post a similar question when I found this one.  I agree 100% that bounty should not preclude closing.

Answer (score 4):

Because deciding what to do with the bounty when closing is a rather complicated issue, and any automatic ways to either refund or destroy the reputation used for a bounty simply with close votes would be abusable. Closing is a reversible action, posting a bounty isn't because a large part of the value of a bounty is in the increase exposure a question gets when featured.

This should not be an issue in the vast majority of cases anyway, bad questions should be closed inside 2 days, and before that no bounty can be offered.

In rare cases where this still is a problem, a moderator can refund the bounty and then close the question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "complicated issue" I freely admit I do not understand the algorithms in use.  I naively assumed that points for bounty came out of the person's rep who set the bounty and therefore refunding it should be easy- apparently not so.  But if a moderator can refund the bounty why can't "the machine"?